# mongodb - count improve performance

Tags: mongodb, performancecounter

I studied the performance mongodb.  I have a collection of 500 millions documents. I created two indexes:

```
db.appels.createIndex({OPERATEUR_RECEVEUR:1});
db.appels.createIndex({DUREE_APPEL:1});
```

count on a field, is fast :

15 seconds :

```
db.appels.find ( {  "DUREE_APPEL" : { "$gt" : 42 } }).count();
```

2 seconds :

```
 db.appels.find({OPERATEUR_RECEVEUR:"MTN"}).count();
```

But count on two fields with an "and", is slow :

7 minutes  :

```
db.appels.find ( { $and : [ {  "DUREE_APPEL" : { "$gt" : 42 } }, {OPERATEUR_RECEVEUR:"MTN"} ] } ).count();
```

(This is the same time without a field index)

Finally, count on two fields with a "or" is impossible :

15 hours and kill query :

```
db.appels.find ( { $or : [ {  "DUREE_APPEL" : { "$gt" : 42 } }, {OPERATEUR_RECEVEUR:"MTN"} ] } ).count();
```

I can not use multi index because I have 100 columns. I use 1 node with debian 8, 2 SSD, 80 Go Ram, 12 Cpu, mongodb 2.4. How can I improve speed?

Comment: Why can't you create index on two fields? In your case  DUREE_APPEL and OPERATEUR_RECEVEUR. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/

Comment: thank you for your reply. 


I do not know in advance what the query, or how many field will be used (sometimes 1, sometimes 2, .. , ... , sometimes 10 ) .


The query is dynamically generated according to the choice of the end user in a web interface.


If I have 100 columns, I have thousands of indexes to create.

Comment: Well, if you don't know upfront, I'd suggest create index on every field. I know your indexes will use extra resources but will increase user experience by returning data fast.

Comment: Create an index on each field = 100 index.

Create Compound Indexes on all fields by two = 500 (approximately) index.

Create Compound Indexes on all three fields = ... ... ... .

Then by 4, 5, 6 ... 10 .

Is this what you recommend?

Comment: Nope. I'm suggesting to have one on each field which is more likely to be searched. Again, use your own best judgement

Answer (score 0):

I found that it is the "count" is slow, not research.
On the same fields the response time is proportional to the number of result

"DUREE_APPEL" : { "$gt" : 42 } --> 198 757 639 record --> 32 seconds

"DUREE_APPEL" : { "$gt" : 800 } --> 11 479 097 record --> 1.9 seconds

"DUREE_APPEL" : { "$gt" : 5000 } --> 833 961 record --> 0.14 second

The indexes are not the only solution, how to solve this problem?

Is used the sharding (50 million lines with 10 node) could be a solution? : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/

Pierre